# Angular 2+ Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/v1/products.json from localhost:4200 to http://makeup-api.herokuapp.com

Tags: angular, http, proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy config file which helps to make a request to makeup-api but go an error:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/v1/products.json from localhost:4200 to http://makeup-api.herokuapp.com (ECONNRESET) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

my proxy config file:

```
{
  "/api": {
      "target": "http://makeup-api.herokuapp.com",
      "secure": false
  }
}
```

angular.json file

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
  }
}
```

my request:

```
this.http.get<IProduct[]>('api/v1/products.json')
```

Comment: Could you specify please the angular version you are using?